# The quantum hall effect and Hofstadter's butterfly spectrum

Tags: topological-insulators, quantum-hall-effect

What is the connection between the [quantum Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Hall_effect) and the [Hofstadter's butterfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter%27s_butterfly) spectrum? I mean, can I understand something about the quantum Hall effect in the Hofstadter's butterfly spectrum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you study the Quantum Hall effect and more precisely the Hall conductivity you learn that the latter is related to certain quantity called the ***Chern Number*** $\; \sigma_{xy}= \frac{-e^{2}}{2\pi\hbar} C \; $   which is also related to ***Berry Phase***.
When you consider particles on a lattice in a magnetic field, the resulting Schrodinger equation (under certain conditions) yields to the Harper equation which gives the *Hofstadter's* spectrum (for rational values of the flux). For this lattice model we can compute the *Chern Number* which leads to the *Hall Conductivity* as mentioned above. This is the only link that I see, hope it helps you a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful.

Comment: you're welcome !